# Does Less have a feature to shorten input type selectors?

Tags: css, less

I have written this css:

```
.form-group > input[type="text"],
.form-group > input[type="text"]:hover,
.form-group > input[type="text"]:active,
.form-group > input[type="password"],
.form-group > input[type="password"]:hover,
.form-group > input[type="password"]:active,
.form-group > input[type="email"],
.form-group > input[type="email"]:hover,
.form-group > input[type="email"]:active {
    max-width: 400px;
}
```

and i know that i can shorten this by writing

```
.form-group > input[type="text"],
.form-group > input[type="password"],
.form-group > input[type="email"] {
    max-width: 400px;
    &:hover,
    &:active {
    }
}
```

Well, the second code part is what i really did write, the first one is just for the dramaturgy of the question, i guess ;)

Now i wonder if there is a feature that allows to group the input type selectors as well, something like this:

```
.form-group > input {
        $:text,password,email
    max-width: 400px;
    &:hover,
    &:active {
    }
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use less like regular CSS applies:

```
.form-group > input {
  &[type="text"], &[type="password"], &[type="email"] {
     &:hover, &:active {
       max-width: 400px;
     }
  }
}
```

The ampersand (`&`) references the `input` element, and you just add a rule for the `type` attribute

Answer (score 2):

No, Less doesn't provide a function like this.

SCSS has a more "programmatic" approach, so there you can do what you wanted using the [@each](http://sass-lang.com/documentation/file.SASS_REFERENCE.html#each-directive) direcive.

Comment: Allthough you did exactly answer my question, which yoavmatchulsky did not, i still accepted his answer since he did provide a solution to shorten my code further. Guess you didn't think i could have an extreme lack of css knowledge...

Comment: What didn't I answer? :\ @marue

Comment: That i was to stupid to know about a feature regular css does provide. I'm sorry for that

Answer (score 2):

[@yoavmatchulsky's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21648217/937377) doesn't cover the case of when there is not `:hover` or `:active`. Here would be the complete solution that would cover everything that you wanted in the first code block of the question:

```
.form-group > input {
  &[type="text"], &[type="password"], &[type="email"] {
    &, &:hover, &:active {
      max-width: 400px;
    }
  }
}
```

This becomes:

```
.form-group > input[type="text"],
.form-group > input[type="password"],
.form-group > input[type="email"],
.form-group > input[type="text"]:hover,
.form-group > input[type="password"]:hover,
.form-group > input[type="email"]:hover,
.form-group > input[type="text"]:active,
.form-group > input[type="password"]:active,
.form-group > input[type="email"]:active {
  max-width: 400px;
}
```